# Add style for plugin setting page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have done plugin for wordpress but I want to add twitter bootstrap css style into setting page for this plugin. My idea was add this code:

```
function my_plugin_admin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-style', plugins_url('style/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style' );
}

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin') {
    add_action( 'admin_print_styles', array($instance, 'my_plugin_admin_styles'));
}
```

But it effects everything and it change menu on left side too. Is possible apply css only for my setting page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a customized CSS file that targeted only things within your section of the plugin settings page. For example, you could build the plugin settings page with a wrapper like so:

```
<section id="mypluginidentifier-settings">
    <!-- all the plugin settings html here -->
</section>
```

Then, in the CSS, just prefix everything with `#mypluginidentifier-settings`.
*where mypluginidentifier = something unique to your plugin.*

i.e.

```
#mypluginidentifier-settings .button {/*button styles*/}
```

Otherwise you will risk conflicting with the wordpress CSS.

This is really a big hassle, though, if you want to include all of bootstrap. I would also absolutely suggest you include your CSS locally within your plugin rather than calling to the hosted version of the file (you would have to, to do this, anyway).

Comment: Have to say, though: is it really necessary? This seems like overkill for a plugin settings page. Not only that, but Wordpress users are accustomed to the UX/design of Wordpress. Would suggest trying to make things fit within Wordpress as well as possible.